# Reading a matrix from a file in C, the file contains values and positions

Tags: c, file, matrix

Hi I am CS student with no prior experience in programming, my teacher gave me this exercise which involves reading a file like this:

```
3 4
2 1 1
1 2 3
8 3 3
```

`3` and `4` are the numbers of rows and columns of a Matrix, then follow groups of three numbers, the first number is the value and the others are the positions I,J.

Here is the resulting matrix:

```
2 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 8 0
```

This should be the Matrix and it fills with 0 if there is no value. I don't know how to make it read this kind of file in order to fill the matrix.

Is it possible to reuse this code on other files like this one?

```
4 6
2 0 0
4 3 0
1 1 2
8 2 2
3 2 4
9 3 4
7 0 5
2 1 5
1 2 5
```

Thank you in advance!

That is what I tried:

```
int **readFile(char *nameFile, int *m, int *n) {
    int **A;
    FILE *fp;
    int i, j;
    int tmp;

    fp = fopen(nameFile, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error readinfile ");
    }
 
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", m, n);
    A = allocMatrix(*m, *n);  // I used calloc in the alloc function 

    for (i = 0; i < *m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &tmp, &i, &j);
            i = i - 1;
            j = j - 1;
            A[i][j] = tmp;
        }
    }
  
    return A;
}
```

In the `for` loops I used `i=i-1` and `j=j-1` because in the first file (but not the second) the positions are `i+1` and `j+1` so I tought I had to fix that.

Comment: `scanf`/`fscanf` would be appropriate.

Comment: Can you show us your code and tell us what doesn't work about it? We're not going to write the code for you. Also, your requirements are incredibly unclear (to me).

Comment: @pmacfarlane: After the number of rows and columns, the input contains multiple lines with three numbers, `a b c`, and the program is supposed to set `matrix[b][c] = a` for each such line and then print the entire matrix. There was another question with the same problem recently.

Comment: You have been taught things in class prior to this assignment: How to read numbers from input, how to define arrays, likely how to allocate space dynamically, how to assign values to elements in arrays, how to print arrays. Which of these things are you having problems with? Can you write a program that simply reads the numbers in the input (assigning their values to `int` objects) and prints them out?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Makes sense now that the formatting is fixed. The version I saw when I commented just had single lines with dozens of digits in a row.

Comment: @ikegami Or `fgets / sscanf` :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hi thank you for the help , I realised this morning that my post was incomplete and not really well written , pardon my mistake. Yes i know pretty much all that is required to do this task as i know how to read numbers from a file and fill a Matrix with them. I will edit the post and add the code I wrote.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Sorry for the bad post, I hope my question is now clear. As you may see I Edited the post and added the solution i wrote that does not work. I tried other similar solutions by changing this a bit but pretty much nothing really did what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that reads the data from stdin.  You can fopen and replace the `scanf()` with `fscanf()` if you want read from a file instead.  If your matrix is large then you want to allocate the `matrix` with `calloc()` instead of a vla.  You would want to evaluate error handling and probably use a suitable named function or two (`matrix_read()`, `matrix_print()`?).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    size_t rows;
    if(scanf("%zu", &rows) != 1) {
        printf("could not read rows\n");
        return 1;
    }
    size_t cols;
    if(scanf("%zu", &cols) != 1) {
        printf("could not read cols\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int matrix[rows][cols];
    memset(matrix, 0, sizeof matrix);
    for(;;) {
        size_t r, c;
        int v;
        int rv = scanf("%d %zu %zu", &v&r, &c);
        if(rv == EOF) break;
        if(rv != 3) {
            printf("could not read entry\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(!r || r > rows  || !c || c > cols) {
            printf("invalid data (%zu, %zu) = %d\n", r, c, v);
            continue;
        }
        matrix[r - 1][c - 1] = v;
    }

    for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            printf("%d%s", matrix[r][c], c +1 <cols ? " " : "\n");
}
```

and here is an example run:

```
$ cat <<EOF | ./a.out
3 4
2 1 1
1 2 3
8 3 3
EOF
2 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 8 0
```